# Jelly - how to call java method with parameters from jelly tag

Tags: jenkins, jelly

I have the following entry in my .jelly file:

```
<j:forEach items="${instance.getVerdictCategoriesList()}" var="p">
    <f:entry title="${%Started}"                             
             field="${p.verdictValue}">
             <f:textbox name="${p.verdictValue}"
                        value="${instance.returnDefaultZeroValue()}"
                        default=""/>
    </f:entry>
```

Currently I'm calling the `${instance.returnDefaultZeroValue()}` and it works.

I want to call a method with multiple parameters. How do I do that?

Like: `value="${instance.getGerritReportingValueForCustomLabel(${p.verdictValue})}"`
but that fails with a "can't parse jelly" error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you meant

```
value="${instance.getGerritReportingValueForCustomLabel(p.verdictValue)}"
```

The `${…}` syntax introduces interpolation of JEXL expressions into what would otherwise be treated as a literal string. It is not part of JEXL itself.

Comment: It worked with 1 parameter, but when I tried passing a string parameter like value="${instance.getGerritReportingValueForCustomLabel(p.verdictValue, SomeStringHere)}" I got a can't parse exception, tried with 'SomeStringHere' as well but ' didn't help. But you're right, with 1 param it works fine

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways of calling Java method using Jelly file
Following are two Objects are used

1. Descriptor: As you now know, Descriptor is configuration class this object points to. So from jelly at any point, you can call the method from your Descriptor class.
2. Instance: This is the object currently being configured on the configuration page. Null if it’s a newly added instance. Means by using this you can call the methods from your Action class. Like getters of field attribute.

You can bind object with jelly using

```js
<st:bind var="backend" value="${descriptor}"/>
```

OR

```js
<st:bind var="instance" value="${instance}"/>
```

The method can be called as backend.{backend method name}().

if you are using this from JavaScript then you need use @JavaScriptMethod annotation over the method being called.